# Implement IEqualityComparer

Tags: c#

I would like to get distinct objects from a list. I tried to implement `IEqualityComparer` but wasn't successful. Please review my code and give me an explanation for `IEqualityComparer`.

```
public class Message
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public string y { get; set; }
    public string z { get; set; }
    public string w { get; set; }
}

public class MessageComparer : IEqualityComparer<Message>
{
    public bool Equals(Message x, Message y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        if (x.x == y.x && x.y == y.y && x.z == y.z && x.w == y.w)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Message number)
    {
        // if (Object.ReferenceEquals(number, null)) return 0;
        int hashX = number.x.GetHashCode();
        int hashY = number.y == null ? 0 : number.y.GetHashCode();
        int hashZ = number.z == null ? 0 : number.z.GetHashCode();
        int hashW = number.w == null ? 0 : number.w.GetHashCode();

        return hashX ^ hashY ^ hashZ ^ hashW;           
    }
}
```

This is my `List` with `Message` objects:

```
Message m1 = new Message();
m1.x = 1;
m1.y = "A";
m1.z = "B";
m1.w = "C";

Message m2 = new Message();
m2.x = 1;
m2.y = "A";
m2.z = "B";
m2.w = "C";

Message m3 = new Message();
m3.x = 1;
m3.y = "A";
m3.z = "B";
m3.w = "C";

Message m4 = new Message();
m4.x = 2;
m4.y = "A";
m4.z = "B";
m4.w = "C";

Message m5 = new Message();
m5.x = 3;
m5.y = "W";
m5.z = "D";
m5.w = "C";

Message m6 = new Message();
m6.x = 4;
m6.y = "S";
m6.z = "F";
m6.w = "R";

List<Message> collection = new List<Message>();
collection.Add(m1);
collection.Add(m2);
collection.Add(m3);
collection.Add(m4);
collection.Add(m5);

collection.Distinct(new MessageComparer());
```

When I call the `Distinct()` method, the number of elements in `collection` are the same.

Comment: Are you assigning the result of the distinct call to a variable or just checking the original list? If you're not assigning to anything, you'll need to. `Distinct()` returns an `IEnumerable` rather than doing an in place update

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
var distinct = collection.Distinct(new MessageComparer());
```

Then use `distinct` for anything after that.

It looks like you're forgetting the immutable nature of `IEnumerable<>`. None of the LINQ methods actually change the original variable. Rather, they return `IEnuerable<T>`s which contain the result of the expression. For example, let's consider a simple `List<string> original` with the contents `{ "a", "a", "b", "c" }`.

Now, let's call `original.Add("d");`. That method has no return value (it's `void`). But if we then print out the contents of `original`, we will see `{ "a", "a", "b", "c", "d" }`.

On the other hand, let's now call `original.Skip(1)`. This method *does* have a return value, one of type `IEnumerable<string>`. It is a LINQ expression, and performs no side-effecting actions on the original collection. Thus, if we call that and look at `original`, we will see `{ "a", "a", "b", "c", "d" }`. However, the result from the method will be `{ "a", "b", "c", "d" }`. As you can see, the result skips one element.

This is because LINQ methods accept `IEnumerable<T>` as a parameter. Consequently, they have no concept of the implementation of the original list. You could be passing, via extension method, a `ReadOnlyCollection` and they would still be able to evaluate through it. They cannot, then, alter the original collection, because the original collection could be written in any number of ways.

All that, but in table form. Each lines starts with the original `{ "a", "a", "b", "c" }`:

```
Context     Example function    Immutable?    Returned Value     Collection after calling
Collection  Add("d")            No            (void)             { "a", "a", "b", "c", "d" }:
LINQ        Skip(1)             Yes           { "a", "b", "c" }  { "a", "a", "b", "c" }:
```

Answer (score 12):

`IEqualityComparer` is an interface which is used to find whether an object is equal or not. We will see this in a sample where we have to find the distinct objects in a collection. This interface will implement the method `Equals(T obj1,T obj2)`.

```
abstract public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { set; get; }
}

public enum SortType
{
    ByID,
    BySalary
}

public class EmployeeDistinctEquality : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeDistinctEquality()
    {

    }

    public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
            return true;
        else if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;
        else if (x.Id == y.Id)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Refer to this link for more detailed information:

http://dotnetvisio.blogspot.in/2015/12/usage-of-icomparer-icomparable-and.html

Comment: in "...if (x == null && x == null)..." I guess you mean: if (x == null && y == null)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to implement `IEqualityComparer`:

```
public class Message
{
    protected bool Equals(Message other)
    {
        return string.Equals(x, other.x) && string.Equals(y, other.y) && string.Equals(z, other.z) && string.Equals(w, other.w);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Message) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked //Ignores overflows that can (should) occur
        {
            var hashCode = x;
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ (y != null ? y.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ (z != null ? z.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ (w != null ? w.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return hashCode;
        }
    }

    public int x { get; set; }
    public string y { get; set; }
    public string z { get; set; }
    public string w { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Depends on the case. If this kind of comparison is just needed in a specific Distinct case, it's better to use a separate comparer. Overriding Equals method affects other places, too.

Comment: It affects other places in a positive way, you generally want to implement it for a data class like this

Comment: I think that's the best answer to the question