# How to get distinct values with corresponding data from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I need to be able to return back only the records that have a unique AccessionNumber with it's corresponding LoginId. So that at the end, the data looks something like:

- A1,L1
- A2,L1
- A3,L2

However, my issue is with this line of code because Distinct() returns a IEnumerable of string and not IEnumerable of string[]. Therefore, compiler complains about string not containing a definition for AccessionNumber and LoginId.

```
yield return new[] { record.AccessionNumber, record.LoginId };
```

This is the code that I am trying to execute:

```
    internal static IEnumerable<string[]> GetTestDataForSpecificItemType(ItemTypes itemTypeCode)
    {
        IEnumerable<StudentAssessmentTestData> data = DataGetter.GetTestData("MyTestData");
        data = data.Where(x => x.ItemTypeCode.Trim() == itemTypeCode.ToString());
        var z = data.Select(x => x.AccessionNumber).Distinct();

        foreach (var record in z)
        {
            yield return new[] { record.AccessionNumber, record.LoginId };
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do with your `Select<TInput, TOutput>` statement where you transform from `StudentAssessmentTestData` to `string` (assuming `AccessionNumber` is of type string)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that finally worked:

```
internal static IEnumerable<string[]> GetTestDataForSpecificItemType(ItemTypes itemTypeCode)
        {
            var data = DataGetter.GetTestData("MyTestData");
            data = data.Where(x => x.ItemTypeCode.Trim() == itemTypeCode.ToString());
            var z = data.GroupBy(x => new{x.AccessionNumber})
                .Select(x => new StudentAssessmentTestData(){ AccessionNumber = x.Key.AccessionNumber, LoginId = x.FirstOrDefault().LoginId});

            foreach (var record in z)
            {
                yield return new[] { record.AccessionNumber, record.LoginId };
            }
        }
```

Returns a sequence that looks like similar to this:

- Acc1, Login1
- Acc2, Login1
- Acc3, Login2
- Acc4, Login1
- Acc5, Login3

Comment: If I understood your question correctly this isn't what you asked for. I thought you were asking for the records returned where there was a unique `AccessionNumber` - in other words, if two or more records had the same `AccessionNumber` then don't return them. This answer is returning only the first records for each `AccessionNumber`. Which was it that you wanted?

Comment: It seems to be the same to me. I wanted one of every single accession number with the corresponding Login without having duplicate values of Accession number. This is exactly what I get with this answer.

Comment: OK, in your question you say "only the records that have a unique `AccessionNumber`" which means if two records have the same `AccessionNumber` then both those records do not have unique values so they shouldn't be returned. That was where my confusion was.

Answer (score 0):

That's cause you are selecting only that property `AccessionNumber` by saying the below

```
var z = data.Select(x => x.AccessionNumber).Distinct();
```

You probably want to select entire `StudentAssessmentTestData` record

```
data = data.Where(x => x.ItemTypeCode.Trim() == itemTypeCode.ToString()).Distinct();

    foreach (var record in data)
    {
        yield return new[] { record.AccessionNumber, record.LoginId };
    }
```

Comment: Still brings back all of the AccessionNumber  values, even non-unique

Comment: @NikolayAdvolodkin, you most probably don't want `distinct` rather want `row_number()` function like stuff. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980568/row-number-over-partition-by-xxx-in-linq

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Distinct`, use `GroupBy`. This:

```
var z = data.Select(x => x.AccessionNumber).Distinct();

foreach (var record in z)
{
    yield return new[] { record.AccessionNumber, record.LoginId };
}
```

should be something like this:

```
return data.GroupBy(x => x.AccessionNumber)
    .Select(r => new { AccessionNumber = r.Key, r.First().LoginId});
```

The `GroupBy()` call ensures only unique entries for `AccessionNumber` and the `First()` ensures that only the first one `LoginId` with that `AccessionNumber` is returned.

This assumes that your data is sorted in a way that if there are multiple logins with the same AccessionNumber, the first login is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose distinct values based on a certain property you can do it in several ways.

If it is always the same property you wish to use for comparision, you can override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in the `StudentAssessmentTestData` class, thus allowing the `Distinct` method to recognize how the classes differ from each other, an example can be found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924071/implement-iequalitycomparer)

However, you can also implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` for your implementation, for example the following version

```
// Custom comparer taking generic input parameter and a delegate function to do matching
public class CustomComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> {
    private readonly Func<T, object> _match;

    public CustomComparer(Func<T, object> match) {
        _match = match;
    }

    // tries to match both argument its return values against eachother
    public bool Equals(T data1, T data2) {
        return object.Equals(_match(data1), _match(data2));
    }

    // overly simplistic implementation
    public int GetHashCode(T data) {
        var matchValue = _match(data);
        if (matchValue == null) {
            return 42.GetHashCode();
        }
        return matchValue.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

This class can then be used as an argument for the [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx) function, for example in this way

```
// compare by access number
var accessComparer = new CustomComparer<StudentTestData>(d => d.AccessionNumber );
// compare by login id
var loginComparer = new CustomComparer<StudentTestData>(d => d.LoginId );

foreach (var d in data.Distinct( accessComparer )) {
    Console.WriteLine( "{0}, {1}", d.AccessionNumber, d.LoginId);
}

foreach (var d in data.Distinct( loginComparer )) {
    Console.WriteLine( "{0}, {1}", d.AccessionNumber, d.LoginId);
}
```

A full example you can find in this [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E53tDc)

Answer (score 0):

Add a LinqExtension method DistinctBy as below.

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
        foreach (TSource element in source)
        {
            if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in your code like this:

**var z = data.DistinctBy(x => x.AccessionNumber);**

```
internal static IEnumerable<string[]> GetTestDataForSpecificItemType(ItemTypes itemTypeCode)
{
    IEnumerable<StudentAssessmentTestData> data = DataGetter.GetTestData("MyTestData");
    data = data.Where(x => x.ItemTypeCode.Trim() == itemTypeCode.ToString());
    var z = data.DistinctBy(x => x.AccessionNumber);

    foreach (var record in z)
    {
        yield return new[] { record.AccessionNumber, record.LoginId };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It works for me.

```
IEnumerable<StudentAssessmentTestData> data = DataGetter.GetTestData("MyTestData");
data = data.Where(x => x.ItemTypeCode.Trim() == itemTypeCode.ToString());
var z = data.GroupBy(x => x.AccessionNumber).SelectMany(y => y.Take(1));

foreach (var record in z)
{
    yield return new[] { record.AccessionNumber, record.LoginId };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. You either want (1) only records with a unique `AccessionNumber` , if two or more records had the same `AccessionNumber` then don't return them, or (2) only the first record for each AccessionNumber.

Here's both options:

(1)

```
internal static IEnumerable<string[]> GetTestDataForSpecificItemType(ItemTypes itemTypeCode)
{
    return
        DataGetter
            .GetTestData("MyTestData");
            .Where(x => x.ItemTypeCode.Trim() == itemTypeCode.ToString())
            .GroupBy(x => x.AccessionNumber)
            .Where(x => !x.Skip(1).Any())
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .Select(x => new [] { x.AccessionNumber, x.LoginId });
}
```

(2)

```
internal static IEnumerable<string[]> GetTestDataForSpecificItemType(ItemTypes itemTypeCode)
{
    return
        DataGetter
            .GetTestData("MyTestData");
            .Where(x => x.ItemTypeCode.Trim() == itemTypeCode.ToString())
            .GroupBy(x => x.AccessionNumber)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))
            .Select(x => new [] { x.AccessionNumber, x.LoginId });
}
```